# Akka stream map with retry

Tags: akka, reactive-programming, akka-stream

How can i retry if mapping/processing of an element in the stream fails?

I have tried setting the decider in materializer but it does not offer retry. It simply maps exception to Supervision stage.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider it as a tip rather than complete answer. I recently implement similar functionality with futures and `mapAsync`. There is a library called [retry](https://github.com/softprops/retry) for retrying futures with different strategies such as pause or back off. But this method have a problem that because akka streams use bounded buffers, if all futures that mapAsync is buffered are failing, your pipeline will stop processing.

Another approach to this problem is building a flow with feedback loop that pushes failed messages back to start. This is better solution since failed ones won't block your pipeline, however, I found that it is harder to implement backoff strategy this way.

Comment: This is great advice, many thanks. Can you by any chance point me to an example of flow with fallback loop?

Comment: I couldn't find any example on this topic so you should create on your own :(

Answer (score 0):

From akka-stream **2.4.4** you can use `recoverWithRetries` (docs [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#recoverWithRetries)).

This basically allows you to provide

1. the number of retry attempts
2. alternative source(s) to switch to depending on the occurred failure

It's available for both `Source` and `Flow`.